# How to manage publication bias

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, bias

My team has been carrying out a meta-analysis study. Through the process, who have statistically detected publication bias, according to Egger's regression test; to consider the suppressed studies to the analysis that have missed during the publication process, we have tried to employ trim and fill analysis.

However, we couldn't find extra studies; originally, the included studies were 20, and the same number of studies produced after conducting the trim and fill analysis.

Could you please clarify this contradicted findings? For your information the heterogeneity was 94%, according to the I2 test.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the funnel plot or the analyzed data? I've come across this before and not all tests will give the same signal. On a related note, I wonder if pooling is even a good idea with such a high I-squared value.